# ASP MVC Enforcing Certain Criteria Before Pages are Available

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, navigation

I'd like some ideas or advice on the best way to tackle this particular problem and I'm wondering if there is an established pattern for dealing with this problem.

I have an MVC application in the process of being built that requires the users to perform certain tasks before some pages are available for navigating too.  There are a few ways I can do this from a presentation perspective such as having menu items disabled etc and only enabled once the criteria are met.

The issue is that I have two separate databases, one with all the security data and one for all the application data.  I could simply have an additional table with a set of booleans to show when a particular step has been completed and then retrieve that on login and act accordingly.

Any idea on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create roles that are area/pages specific.  After a user has completed whatever it is they need to complete, then add them to the role.

This allows you to use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

```
[Authorize(roles = "CompletedSurvey")]
public class MyClassController ...
```

or

```
[Authorize(roles = "CompletedSurvey")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()...
```

Comment: That is an interesting idea actually.  Really hadn't considered that at all.  Thanks.

Comment: In fact I think you may well have just totally solved this problem.  The more I think about it the more sense it makes.

Comment: The only problem with this is that I now need to figure out a way of nicely presenting multiple links to other pages based on this.  I need a custom filter I think.

Comment: What do you mean presenting links?